# Summing up the values in the stream several times

Tags: java, java-stream

I am looking for a solution to the problem using streams:

I have a sample list:

`List.of(1,3,5,7)`

I would like to add a given element with each next element in the stream ie.

1+3+5+7

3+5+7

5+7

and at the end add up the whole result and return it.
In this case, the result would be 43.

Is this reasonably possible or is it better to use for loops?

Comment: This can porbably be achieved using `Stream`'s `skip` method. However a regular loop is probably more suited and more readable.

Comment: How big is the list?  If it's large, then there will be many repeated operations (non-performant). Consider working backwards, and save intermediate steps for re-use.

Comment: Is there a reason you only want `1+3+5+7` + `3+5+7` + `5+7` as a result and ignore the last element `7`? If it would be `1+3+5+7` + `3+5+7` + `5+7`+ `7` you could literally just simplify the whole calculation to a formula where you sum up every element of the list with its index incremented by one like `int result = list.get(0) * 1 + list.get(1) * 2 ... + list.get(n) * (n+1)`

Comment: @AndrewS In this case, a maximum of 100 values.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Due to the task specification, I am given a list of x-numbers and I need to count the sum in such a way that the last element is omitted. Alternatively, I can always subtract the last element from the total.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this reasonably possible or is it better to use for loops?

Yes it's possible.  Loops would probably be more efficient as streams incur some overhead.  But the idea of streams is to provide declarative programming techniques (what to do) of accomplishing something which should be more obvious than imperative programming (how to do it).

There are several ways.  This stream solution provided by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) works in linear time. It iterates over the list, summing the number of times each item would occur in the final sum.  Since it also sums the last entry of the list (which is not desired) that is subtracted out.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,3,5,7);

int sum = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
      .map(i -> list.get(i) * (i + 1))
      .sum() - list.get(list.size() - 1);

System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
43
```

Here is a loop version using the same algorithm.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sum += list.get(i)*(i+1);
}
sum -= list.get(list.size()-1);
```

Although the loop version may be more efficient, this is a rather trivial case and the solutions are practically identical.  Complex software may better lend itself to declarative coding style.

And there are other considerations that use hybrid solutions such as using a loop in unison with java 8+ enhancements (the [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) comes to mind).

The approach taken can depend on things such as increasing productivity in writing software and being able to diagnose a problem in code that you haven't seen in a year or more.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the *[IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)* class to iterate the *List* similar to a *for-loop*.

Here is an example.

```java
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,3,5,7);
int sum
    = IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1)
               .map(x -> list.stream().skip(x)
                                      .mapToInt(y -> y)
                                      .sum())
               .sum();
```